# EDMX and Source control

Tags: c#, version-control, entity-framework-6

Whenever someone changes the EDMX in source control and I get latest I have to goto the EDMX and save it so it will generate the .tt files. Should the .tt files be add to source control or how can I prevent this from being a issue

[image: Project]

Comment: the TT files transform the EDMX into the .cs files

Comment: Yes so should the .cs class be checked into source control ?

Comment: I add them except the Designer.cs this is a stub and changes if the path changed